# How to append a float value as float in dictionary?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I need to calculate a MD5 values with a json value to the server like,

```
{
  "name":"swift",
  "version":1.0,
  "edition":1,
  "date":"2014-12-26"
 }
```

In this json the version needs to be send as float `1.0` not `1` and edition as integer `1`.

So, I have tried to create a dictionary and done a `NSJSONSerialization` as,

```
NSDictionary *d = @{@"name":@"swift",
@"version":[NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:@"1.0"],
@"edition":[NSNumber numberWithInt:1],@"date":@"2014-12-26"}; 
NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:d options:0 error:nil];
```

But this is creating a json response as

```
{
  "name":"swift",
  "version":1,
  "edition":1,
  "date":"2014-12-26"
}
```

So the `MD5` value is mismatching.

Can anyone help me with this to create a json with float value for "version" with decimal point `(1.0)` ?

Comment: As a string you can get it with [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.1f", 1.f] where 1.f is your float.

Comment: @zero - Quite wrong.  A number must be encoded as an NSNumber (or NSDecimalNumber) to add to a JSON object.  If you encode it as a string it will appear in the JSON in quotes and will be received as a string on the other end, not the intended number.

Comment: Thought so (but I never used JSON) - just wanted to make sure that the OP knows about "Format String Specifiers".

Comment: I don't think that it's sensible to try to compare the MD5 sums of JSON representation of a data structure. JSON can be formatted in a lot of different ways that doesn't change its meaning. For example, the whitespace is effectively arbitrary. JSON does not distinguish between floating-point and integer numbers. In the case of Cocoa, numbers will be wrapped in `NSNumber` which is documented to not preserve the original type with which it was constructed.

Comment: Yep, the only reason for calculating a checksum on the JSON would be to compare the transmitted value to the received value, to detect corruption during transmission.  One should never expect two separately-constructed JSON strings to be bit-for-bit identical or have the same checksum.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with sending the numeric value `1.0` as simply `1` in JSON.  Though you might have a little luck getting the `.0` if you encoded a floating point in an NSNumber, vs using an NSDecimalNumber.

```
`... @"version":@(1.0)...`
```

The full dictionary:

```
NSDictionary *d = @{@"name":@"swift",
@"version":@(1.0),
@"edition":@(1),
@"date":@"2014-12-26"};
```

Answer (score 0):

Create the `NSMutableDictionary`, convert the number to an `NSNumber` and put it into the `NSMutableDictionary`.

```
NSMutableDictionary *dict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];

float value = 1.0;

NSNumber *number = [NSNumber numberForFloat:value];
[dict setObject:number forKey:@"version"];
```

or using literals replace the above two lines with:

```
dict[@"version"] = @(value);
```